# Is it possible to successfully clone (with dd) a Linux OS disk between different sized/models SSDs?

Tags: linux, boot, clone, bootable-media, dd

I have a CentOS installed on quite an old SSD.
The SSD indicates hardware problems in the syslog.

I suspect that the answer to the following is ***no***, especially due to superblocks and boot-sectors placement but -

*Is it possible to successfully clone (with dd) a Linux OS disk between different sized/models SSDs?*

Specifically, would the following do?

```
$ dd if=/dev/oldSSD of=/dev/newSSD bs=64K conv=noerror,sync
```

Answer (score 2):

That *should* be fine so long as the new SSD is bigger or *at least* the same size as the old SSD... You'll need to compare capacity at the byte level, a "*500 GB*" disk isn't necessarily exactly the same capacity as another "*500 GB*" disk

However, things to watch out for:

- Don't have the source filesystem(s) mounted, or at least remount everything read only.
- Corruption or read errors from the old SSD - most filesystems aren't able to determine if file content is damaged or incorrect.
- Page size or alignment in the filesystem vs underlying storage - for example if the old SSD has 2 kB pages, while new SSD has 16 kB pages.
- Once you've made the clone, you'll probably want to resize partitions and filesystems to use any additional space.
- If it's an old disk, it may well be an old OS... are you sure a fresh install of a modern release isn't a better solution? You can still pull data off the old SSD later.
- Disk and filesystem IDs will be identical, which can cause issues when attempting to address the new / old data - for example, see `tune2fs -U random` for ext2/3/4 filesystems.

---

If you're suspicious of the source disk, I'd probably recommend `ddrescue`, and make sure you keep a log file.

Increasing the block size passed to `dd` to ~4 - 8 MB could reduce the time significantly, both due to less system calls and matching target SSD's erase block size. It could also potentially incur less wear on the target SSD.

Comment: Good, do note that when you `dd`, the `UUID` becomes the same, this confuses Linux, so detach the old drive BEFORE starting from the new drive. So do a shutdown, disconnect old drive, boot.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I've added a note about `tune2fs`.